# Onclick of Fab Button i have a Form and i have to Save it in SQL

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-button, floating-action-button

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_customer);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ds = new DataSource(getApplicationContext());

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            myDialog = new Dialog(view.getContext());
            myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup_add_customers);

            btnSave = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
            btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "savebutton", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

            myDialog.show();
        }
    });
}
```

For now i just want to get a toast on Save Button..

It Gives me an error that is below

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
```

Thanks in advance Really need help ...

Comment: btnSave button it inside FAB button.

Comment: if you want to perform save on fab click then why inside put button click event. it not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onclick listener on button in dialog force closes app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17376147/onclick-listener-on-button-in-dialog-force-closes-app)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is at btnSave findViewById

change like this

```
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            myDialog = new Dialog(view.getContext());
            myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup_add_customers);

            btnSave = (Button)myDialog.findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
            btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "savebutton", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

            myDialog.show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to `findViewById` the `btnSave` inside your activity, while it is inside a dialog. You need to call `findViewById` on a dialog:

```
btnSave = (Button)myDialog.findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not put this

```
btnSave = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "savebutton", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

in OnClick method you need to put this in the OnCreate method

Try This:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_customer);
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
ds = new DataSource(getApplicationContext());
 btnSave = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "savebutton", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
  FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
   fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        myDialog = new Dialog(view.getContext());
        myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup_add_customers);



        myDialog.show();
    }
});
}
```

Comment: But your answer will be wrong if save button will be inside dialog layout